# Reading from config.properties file Maven project

Tags: java, maven

I'm new in maven and java , i imported maven project , it has config.properties file , this file contains

```
PATH_TO_QUERY_FILE=abc.txt
```

and class that using the property from the config.properties like

```
queryFile = prop.getProperty("PATH_TO_QUERY_FILE");
```

Should i add real path for this file in config to make code read it while running ? like

```
PATH_TO_QUERY_FILE=/home/user/workspace/project/abc.txt
```

or not ?

- when i `mvn package` project i didn't find this files in the jar file which is created , Is this because of real path that i'm asking about or not ?

[image]

Coder used this statements

`FileInputStream finputstream = new FileInputStream(
                    "/home/user/workspace/project/config.properties");
            prop.load(finputstream);
            queryFile = prop.getProperty("PATH_TO_QUERY_FILE");
            fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(
                    prop.getProperty("PATH_TO_OUTPUT_FILE")));
            finputstream.close();`

Comment: You should add a portion of maven snippet if you want some help

Comment: Is your file in the src\main\resources directory of your project? Files in this directory will be included in the jar.

Comment: sorry for late reply , i edited post with screenshot of projet i imported

Comment: i didn't make resources folder , should i make it ? and which files should i put it  ?

Comment: if  you want to put the properties file in one separate folder then you have to specify "foldername/*.properties" while reading the properties

Answer (score 14):

It depends on how you're planning to distribute your application. And on how you're reading the files. Basically there'are two options: reading from files and reading from classpath.

**1. Reading from files.**

If you're using this path by passing it to a `File` constructor or passing to some FileStream, than you should know that your paths will be resolved relative to working folder. Working folder is basically the one, from which you initiate `java -cp .. some.MainClass` command. In that case you will have to copy `config.properties` file with you and run your command from appropriate directory. File configs are more flexible in a way, that you will not have to rebuild your application (or repack manually), if you will want to change some values in that config. If you're not really planning to change values after distribution, than usually it's better to pack it in jars and read as a resource.

**2. Reading from resources.**

Java has a mechanism to read resources from classpath. To do so, you first need to pack resources in your usual jars, that goes to classpath. Then you can load them in your programm by obtaining the appropriate classloader reference. Usually you just use any class in context:

```
InputStream s = AnyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/config.properties");
//or shortcut version
InputStream s = AnyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/config.properties");

//now can use this input stream as usually, i.e. to load as properties
Properties props = new Properties();
props.load(inputStream);
```

Now for your question on how to use this resource loading properly with maven. By default maven packs all files in `<MODULE_DIR>/src/main/resources` into the resulting jar. So all you need is to place your `abc.txt` into `<MODULE_DIR>/src/main/resources/whatever/abc.txt` and load it as `...getResourceAsStream("/whaterver/abc.txt")`. That will work no matter, how you're running your app: from IDE or after packaging. Than do with it whatever you've done.

Comment: thanks for your great illustration , i edited post with code that coder used it